# Javascript Best Practise: Syncing Browser Windows

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronization

I have an html5/javascript application in which multiple users can be viewing the same set of data of any given time. For the sake of a real world example, lets say its a calendar type page.

So user1 is looking has the browser open and looking at the calendar page and user2 is also on the calendar page. User2 makes a change to the calendar and i'd like (as quickly as possible) for those changes the be recognized and refreshed on user1's screen. What is the best way to do this?

I'm thinking about have a mysql table for active users that stores the page they are currently on and a timestamp for its last update, then use ajax calls to ping the server every few seconds and check for an updated timestamp, if its newer than what they have client side, the new data gets sent and the page "reloaded." I am putting reloaded in quotes because the actual browser window will not be refreshed, but a function will be called via javascript that will reload the page. Sort of the way stack overflow performs its update checks, but instead of telling the user the page has changed and providing a button for reload, it should happen automatically. If user1 is working away on the calendar, it seems it might be quite annoying for user2's screen to constantly be refreshing...

Is this a horrible idea? Is pinging the server with an ajax request every few seconds going to cause major slow downs? Is there a better way to do this? I would like the views on either users side to be real time because its important that user1 not be able to update an element on the calendar page that user2 has already changed.

Update: based on some web sockets research it doesnt seem like a proper solution. First its not compatible with older browsers and i support ie8+ and second i dont need real time updstes for all users on the site. The site is an account based applicatiin and an account can have multiple users. The data needs to sync between those users only. Any other recommendations would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need realtime app for this. You should have a look at socketio. Everytime a user log in, you make him listen for changes on the server. Then when something changed on the server, every users listening are notified.
you can find examples on the official website : http://socket.io/

Comment: I'd prefer to roll out my own solution. Any idea how this sort of thing works so I can research how to start implementing a similar approach in my own code?

Comment: Socket.io is the superior choice here.
Long Polling - what you describe is slower than the websocket solution by socket.io.
Also a rule of thumb: mysql is slow when inserting data and should not be used for real time applications like the one you suggest.

If you want to deploy a persistence layer research Redis, CouchDB, MangoDB or general NoSQL solutions.
Middleware choices: Node.js and Websockets.

Comment: So maybe use a static list of some sort rather than mysql? I should mention I use java as a backend and have written a the application without using a nosql, node or any 3rd party solutions. I can't really implement them now as it would mean basically rewritting the entire application.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because web sockets is the most effective way to do my objective, however I won't be using it because of browser compatibility. Instead i'll implement long polling and will update my question with references as I find them.